# Trapezoidal integration program doesn't return a reasonable value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, calculus

Why doesn't this code to integrate the area under a sin curve return a reasonable value? (edited to include a bunch of suggestions)

//I want to write a program that takes the area under a curve by outputting the sum of the areas of n rectangles

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

double interval(double d, double n)
{
    return d / n;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double xmax = 20;                   //upper bound
    double xmin = 2;                    //lower bound 
    double line_length = xmax - xmin;   //range of curve
    double n = 1000;                    //number of rectangles
    vector<double> areas;
    double interval_length = interval(line_length, n);
for (double i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    double fvalue = xmin + i;
    areas.push_back((interval_length * sin(fvalue)) + (0.5 * interval_length * (sin(fvalue + 1) - sin(fvalue))));
    //idea is to use A = b*h1 + 1/2 b*h2 to approximate the area under a curve using trapezoid area
}
```

I added fvalue, interval_length and fixed the logic a bit

```
 double sum_areas = accumulate(areas.begin(), areas.end(), 0.0);
       //accumulate takes each element in areas and adds them together, beginning with double 0.0
        cout << "The approximate area under the curve is " << '\n';
        cout << sum_areas << '\n';
        //this program outputs the value 0.353875, the actual value is -.82423
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: _"#include "../../../../../Desktop/C++/stroustrupheaders/std_lib_facilities.h" "_ Blimey

Comment: You could store values that are repeated several times into a variable to avoid unnecessary recomputation.

Comment: Did you try increasing the value of n and see what happens?

Comment: sorry! I just haven't used the standard library stuff much. I do know that for this program, it lets me use the vector class and namespace std. I simply didn't know what to include to use those two.

Comment: Yeah, I tried many values of n. It doesn't approach the correct value much further.

Comment: Try to write down formulas first: it's unclear what is b and h in terms of x and y = sin(x). Sin(i) ans sin(i+1) look suspicious: sin should be function of x, not loop variable.

Comment: @ShadowMitia, thanks for the suggestion! That definitely makes a lot of sense and the code looks nicer/compiles faster.

Comment: @ivan_onys my plan was to use the loop variable to get the next point in the curve. Is there a more reasonable way to do that?

Comment: The `sin` function expects a value understood to be in radians.  The value you are passing to the `sin` function isn't well understood no matter how I stare at it.

Comment: @selbie yes, thank you for pointing out my faulty logic! Does this loop make more sense? (see my edit to the loop)

Comment: I think my problem is that I want to increase the value of x in sin(x) in the loop, but I can't figure out how to do it properly

Answer (score 0):

The code below doesn't mix using loop variable and x. It has a drawback (same as yours code) that error summing dx is accumulated i.e. dx*n != xmax-xmin. To account for this particular error one should calculate current x as function of i (loop variable) on each iteration as x = xmin + (xmax - xmin)*i/n.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double sum(double xmin, double xmax, double dx)
{
    double rv = 0;

    for (double x = xmin + dx; x <= xmax; x += dx)
        rv += (sin(x) + sin(x-dx)) * dx / 2;

    return rv;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 1000;
    double xmin = 0;
    double xmax = 3.1415926;
    std::cout << sum(xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/n) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the interval length in the function argument

```
double fvalue = xmin + i;
areas.push_back((interval_length * sin(fvalue)) + (0.5 * interval_length * (sin(fvalue + 1) - sin(fvalue))));
```

Should instead be

```
double fvalue = xmin + i*interval_length;
areas.push_back((interval_length * sin(fvalue)) + (0.5 * interval_length * (sin(fvalue + interval_length) - sin(fvalue))));
```

The second line can be better written as

```
areas.push_back(interval_length * 0.5 * (sin(fvalue + interval_length) + sin(fvalue));
```